# Connection between ms sql server 2008 and java swing application on netbeas

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, sql-server-2008, netbeans

Some problem with connection with database on ms sql server 2008 .Compiler gives me following mistake " incorrect syntax near "="; " . Can't find any mistake by myfelf. will be glad if someone helps me.

So, here is code :

```
 /*
  * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project      Properties.
  * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
  * and open the template in the editor.
  */
 package sklad;
 import java.sql.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 /**
  *
  * @author Имба
  */


   public class conexion {

     //    private static final String JDBCDriver ="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
 //   private static final String ConnectionStr =      "jdbc:sqlserver:/localhost:1433;user=sa;password=asdf;databaseName = StoreDB";
         public String user = "sa";
    public String password = "asdf";
    public String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;
     databaseName=StoreDB";

    public Connection cn = null;
    public Statement st = null;

    public Statement Conectar()
    {
 try
 {
 Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);

           st=cn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

 }
 catch (SQLException i)
 {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i);

 }
 return st;
 }


}
```

Comment: What is the line number and what is the code?

Answer (score 0):

Have this in a single line, without a line break...

```
public String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=StoreDB";
```

Comment: actually it is written in a single line, it is mistake when I paste code here ;)

Comment: And still you have the issue? What is the line number where you are getting the error?

Comment: Yes I  have. So that is part of question ? Can't find it. I think that mistake is near symbol "=" :)

Comment: Thank you to all! I solve this problem , there was some problem with creation of database in ms sql 2008

Answer (score 0):

Start by putting your `url` on a single line, like this:

```
public String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=StoreDB";
```

Java does not allow multi-line string literals.

Beyond that, this class is poor design because it doesn't clean up after itself.

Comment: actually it is written in a single line, it is mistake when I paste code here. Ok, I will work on this.Do you know how to do it? :)